# How to automatically switch to https when navigating to http on vite dev server

Tags: https, vite, devserver

When I type `localhost:3000` on my browser it autocompletes to `http://localhost:3000`, while my dev server is configured to run on `https`.

Configuring the dev server to open the app on a new tab when the dev server starts

```
{
  server: {
    open: true
  }
}
```

is helpful, but it doesn't solve the manual navigation mistake.

[This thread](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/13164) on Vite's Github repo discusses it, but the suggestion isn't great.

Answer (score 0):

To automatically navigate to `https` when navigating to `http` add the [HSTS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) header to your `vite.config.ts` server response headers:

```js
const oneYearInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;

export default defineConfig(() => ({
  server: {
    https: true,
    headers: {
      'Strict-Transport-Security': `max-age=${oneYearInSeconds}`
    },
  },
})
```

To later clear the cached HSTS entry on your browser (that expires based on `max-age`) use the delete option on `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`